# React with Webpack - package a module for use in Dynamic loading in another site

Tags: reactjs, split, webpack, redux

I'm using Webpack as our build/bundler for an application using a standard React/Redux/etc.

We have a requirement to build out custom components that can be loaded dynamically into the main application. This would require that the component is created OUTSIDE the main development so would not be involved in the main app build. The ideal solution would be to build out the components in their own side projects, bundle up (since they will have imports/require, etc) and spit out a bundle.js file that is only that component (could be multiple components merged together). Then we'd like to be able to take that file and dynamically load it in the main application dynamically.

I understand how code splitting works with webpack to a certain degree which we use in our main project. I've also been able to successfully import SIMPLE components externally I built out externally. The problem is that these external components can get pretty hefty so using a build/bundler to put it all together in one package would be ideal. I have no idea how to go about building components externally from the main project, bundle up using webpack to merge in all of the goodies into one package and inject that new bundled component which is typically wrapped in webpackjsonp and all the other runtime stuff.

Has anybody else been able to do something crazy like this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I've been able to successfully build a silo component in it's own project using webpack and dynamically loading that into a different running application bundled with webpack by using the Output.Library options as described [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html)

Below is the sample config I used for testing a custom react component called TestMe located inside the index.js file of the test folder.

```
module.exports = {
entry: {
    developer: "./test"
},
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist", "static", "developer"),
    filename: "MyLibrary.[name].js",
    library: ["MyLibrary", "[name]"],
    libraryTarget: "var"
},
externals: {
    'react': 'React'
    , 'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
    , 'react-dom/server': 'ReactDOMServer'
    , 'react/lisb/ReactTransitionGroup': 'React.addons.TransitionGroup'
    , 'react/lib/ReactCSSTransitionGroup': 'React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup'
}, ...
```

When imported in you will have access to the TestMe component as a global variable MyLibrary.developer.TestMe (or MyLibrary.developer.default depending on how you exported the component). The externals are there to keep Webpack from including those in the final bundle which was already included in the main application. Otherwise you're going to get a really big nasty bundle file. Check out LibraryTarget if you rather have UMD, etc.

Moral of the story here is "when all else fails, read the docs again".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  How do I ask a good question?